# Swift IOS Custom Action in Number Detection

Tags: ios, swift, string, format, nsattributedstring

In our App, we have an outbound VOIP phone dialer.

I would like to detect numbers within a string and add a custom action so that instead of the default behaviour to open the native dialer, it will go to our own dialler within the App and pre-populate the selected number.

My first thoughts were to get the body of the message into a string array of words and check each word to see if it is a number and then create an attributed string. But I'm struggling to understand how I can get an attributed string back into a string and what I would even specify to open the said screen with the number pre-populated.

I am aware of NSDataDetector which can list the numbers found in the string but I am stuck with how to replace those particular parts with a clickable action and return it back as a string.

If anyone has had similar experiences with this then any help would be much appreciated?

**NOTE** : The body of this message is being show in a UILabel control.

**Update**

this is what I had so far...

```
    func AddNumberLink() -> String {    
    let body = self     
    let wordsInBody = body.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)

    for i in 0..<wordsInBody.count {            
        var word = wordsInBody[i]           
        if word.isTelephoneNumeric {            
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:word)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value:"https://www.google.com",range: NSRange(location: 0, length: word.count))



  attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor,value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:0, length: word.count))
        word = attributedString.string
        }       
    }
return body
}
```

Comment: Can you pls share code of what you have done so far or explain with better example?

Comment: `UITextView` + `NSDataDetector` might triggers the  `UITextViewDelegate`  method `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`. Don't use a `UILabel` if you want it to be touchable. That's not designed for. There are external lib that allows it, but that's not its initial purpose. See at 2:30 there https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/221/

Answer (score 1):

`NSDataDetector` gives you the ranges of the numbers. Now, create a (mutable) attributed string and for each range, add a link to the corresponding number URL (`NSAttributedString.Key.link: urlString`).
Then, display the text in a `UITextView` and add a delegate.
In the delegate, implement `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool`
In this function, you can decide what action is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this method a go, how do you suggest that I join it all back together again. For example: "Call me back on 0800123001"

Comment: If as I suggested the `NSDataDetector` triggers already the UITextViewDelegate method, there is no need in creating a `NSAttributedString`, except if you want some customization, but even that can be changed with the `linkTextAttributes` property of `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions it has made me approach the problem in a different manner to my code above.

Like @Lutz and @Larme suggested above, by overriding the default behaviour when the UITextView is tapped I can gather the number via the UITextViewDelegate.

So the complete solution is :

1. Add number detector attribute to UITextView
2. Implement UITextViewDelegate func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
3. Add custom logic to handle the tap accordingly.